# A question about $cov(I)$

Tags: set-theory

Given a set $X$ and an ideal $I \subseteq \mathcal P(X)$,

> $cov(I) := \min \{ |\mathcal A| | \mathcal A \subseteq I (\bigcup \mathcal A = X)\}$.

My question is: isn't it possible that for each $\mathcal A \subseteq I$, $\bigcup \mathcal A \neq X$? In this case, what will $cov(I)$ be?

Thank you!

Comment: $\mathrm{min}\{|\mathcal A|\mid\mathcal A\subseteq I\land\bigcup I\subseteq\bigcup\mathcal A\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that given any ideal $I$ on $X$, then $I$ is an ideal on any $X'\supseteq X$. But if $X'\neq X$ then $\bigcup I\neq X'$ since $\bigcup I\subseteq X$.

But at the same time, if $I$ is an ideal on $X$, it is also an ideal on $\bigcup I$. So we may assume without loss of generality that $X=\bigcup I$.

Formally, you're right. If $\bigcup I\subsetneqq X$ then the definition is problematic.

Comment: I see.. ok. Thank you!